# BeautifulSoup is returning just the first statement of Xml

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to parse an XML generated in a browser using BeautifulSoup. However, only the first line is returned.

Given the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<IM415 xmlns="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/customs/IM415">   
  <Declaration>
    <MsgType>H1</MsgType>
    <DeclarationType_1_1>IM</DeclarationType_1_1>
    <AdditionalDeclarationType_1_2>A</AdditionalDeclarationType_1_2>
    <LRN_2_5>NIK243104_16nUlp</LRN_2_5>
    <ValuationInformation>
      <InvoiceCurrency_4_10>AFA</InvoiceCurrency_4_10>
      <InvoiceAmount_4_11>5000</InvoiceAmount_4_11>
      <InternalCurrency_4_12>AFA</InternalCurrency_4_12>
    </ValuationInformation>
    <GoodsInformation>
      <GrossMass_6_5>33300</GrossMass_6_5>
      <TotalPackageNumber_6_18>1665</TotalPackageNumber_6_18>
    </GoodsInformation>
  </Declaration>
</IM415>
```

And the following Python script:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url1 = driver.current_url  
response = requests.get(url1) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
print(soup)
```

I get the following result:

```
MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning: The input looks more like a filename than markup. You may want to open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Where I'm expecting the full document content, shown above, to be included.

Comment: Please edit your question. Use code blocks for the XML and Python code, not quotation.

Comment: BTW, the point of asking for your code to be provided is so we can run it ourselves to see the problem and test our fixes. When you add things like `>` prefixes to each line so it's no longer valid code ready to copy-and-paste, or trim off closing elements that are needed for XML to be valid, then you're making your problem non-reproducible (by anyone who doesn't do work to repair it, but doing that repair risks introducing new bugs, so generally we frown on people other than the OP doing it -- it's your job to ask a question that's self-contained and ready to answer).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I've made the changes as suggested. Can you highlight more when you say 'request the root element'.

Comment: I'm basically expecting the exact same content to be printed. I'll then make a copy of the content to another file for Xml comparison

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce the problem -- see https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/68148b38eb63164cab690a789b47e00d; when I run your code (without the HTTP request nobody but you can run), the full document is returned.

Comment: What is the expected output of your code?